# How can create a live multiplication using nested attributes and combobox option selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, nested, nested-forms, live

I know that my question is really strange or doesn't make sense or will have points down but I investigated about this and didn't found an example about my demo.

I created a nested form so when I add a new row give me a long name like this

```
<input id="shopping_document_shopping_products_attributes_0_qty" name="shopping_document[shopping_products_attributes][0][qty]" size="9" type="text">
<input id="shopping_document_shopping_products_attributes_1_qty" name="shopping_document[shopping_products_attributes][1][qty]" size="9" type="text">
<input id="shopping_document_shopping_products_attributes_2_qty" name="shopping_document[shopping_products_attributes][2][qty]" size="9" type="text">
....
<input id="shopping_document_shopping_products_attributes_X_qty" name="shopping_document[shopping_products_attributes][X][qty]" size="9" type="text">
```

So I will have infinite rows but I'm trying to do a multiplication in each row with the amount selected and finally get the total sum

```
<input id="shopping_document_shopping_products_attributes_0_qty" name="shopping_document[shopping_products_attributes][0][qty]" size="9" type="text">

<option value="">Seleccione</option><option value="106">Impresora RG</option>
  <option value="107">Celular Galaxy J. Astete</option>
  <option value="108">Trapo</option></select>
</option>
```

Notice that name= "shopping_document[shopping_products_attributes][X][qty]" so It should be able to work more than 4 rows in the demo , the symbol X means that if I add a 5 row the live multiplication will work

Here is the example:

[image]

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cmorales/puz6www4/12/)

Please somebody can help me to create this?

I will really appreciate all kind of help.

Don't be bad with me ,I'm just try to learn but didn't found an example with this case

A friend from stackoverflow gave me this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cmorales/bu8da52u/2/)
but I'm using prototype 1.6.0.3 and jquery min 1.4.0 here in the demo works perfect but In production is making conflicts and showing errors and the rest of actions are not working correctly.

Here is the screenshoot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/bu8da52u/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var tbl = $("#products");
    //clone the first row for later duplication
    var tmplt = $(tbl).find("tr").eq(1).clone();

    //when add button is clicked add a row
    tbl.on("click", ".add", function(){
        tmplt.clone().appendTo(tbl);    });

    //when the remove button is clicked
    tbl.on("click", ".remove", function(){
        //Remove if there is more than just one row 
        if(tbl.find("tr").length > 2){
            $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        }
    });

    //calculate the sum
    tbl.on("change keyup", ".qty input, .product select, .cost select", function(){
        var sum = parseFloat($(this).parent().parent().find(".qty input").val()) * parseFloat($(this).parent().parent().find(".cost select").val());
        $(this).parent().parent().find(".sum input").val(sum.toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Sam, worked in jsfiddle but is not working in my example can you check this please? http://jsfiddle.net/cmorales/bu8da52u/2/ is not working with my prototype and jquery min 1.4....thanks in advance

Comment: in this fiddle you did not include any jQuery, from the right sidebar, you should choose a jquery version where it says "Pure JS"

Comment: I did I added external links

Comment: I see, so what the problem exactly?

Comment: I'm having errors and all the actions or updates that I have won't work  look the last image on the post.

Comment: This is because you are using jQuery and Prototype in the same page, to solve this, you must add <script>jQuery.noConflict();</script> after the jquery include script tag

Comment: Do you mean after jquery min 1.4 or jquery min 1.8 ?

Comment: Ok I did it now..I'm getting "Uncaught typeError:Cannot read property 'find' of null"